# Включение питания ПК по средствам BIOS

Tags: загрузка

Бодрого всем здравия.
Вопрос такой:
Если в BIOS нет функции WakeUP (вкл.по времени)
То это всё? ПК по времени ни как не вкл.?
(мать Elitegroup G31T-M7)

Comment: > Включение питания ПК по средствам BIOSВключение питания ПК НЕ по средствам BIOS. Точка. Предлагаю формулировку "Включение питания ПК посредствОм BIOS"

Answer (score 1):

Если очень нужно а функционала нет я бы поставил рядом что-нибудь типа Raspberry Pi которая бы включала ПК по запросу из сети или по питанию замыкая контакты кнопки питания.

Comment: Всё-таки нашёл время и поковырялся в настройках БИОС.  Вспомнил что там было включение от мышки, клавиатуры и прочего.  И подумал, значит обязательно должен присутствовать будильник!  Ваш ответ подтолкнул меня на эту мысль.